# Footer in Communication sites + Hub Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site, hub-site

Is it possible to have the Footer of a Communication site (Hub) to be propagated to the associate sites to that Hub like it happens with the Hub menu/navigation?

Answer (score 1):

I really would like to have this feature too!

For a global intranet look and feel with a clear leveled out look and feel the footer is as essential as the hub menu and both should come back as a pair with the rest of the look and feel across all associated sites.

Created an uservoice idea: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/38331166-footer-of-the-hub-site-to-propagate-to-all-associa